# Build System for Targeting Multiple .NET Versions

Tags: .net, msbuild, project-management, version-control

What are common practices for designing a build system/project structure that allows targeting multiple .NET versions with different feature sets?

Specifically:

- Should you branch in source control?
- Should you use conditional compilation?
- Should you derive interfaces, thereby versioning them?
- Should you create seperate "versionX" projects and link common project files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried a few different ways of doing this.

I ruled out branching because it's a bit difficult to keep all the branches in sync using SVN/TFS. Distributed SCC does have more advanced support for branching/merging, so I'm planning to reconsider this approach if I ever convert.

I use conditional compilation along with version-specific projects using linked source files. The most aggressive library I've done along these lines is [Nito.Linq](http://nitolinq.codeplex.com/), which hasn't been released yet. You can check out the source, though, to see how I've set up the projects. It [currently targets](http://nitolinq.codeplex.com/releases/view/47235) 3.5, 4.0, SL3, and SL4, and has "with Rx" and "without Rx" variants for each of these. I had CF 3.5 working as well, but VS2010 doesn't support it.

There are a few drawbacks to this approach:

- In my solution, I defined a "Sources" project that acts as a container for the files. Unfortunately, it's built when loaded and I can't add source files when it's unloaded; so it ends up getting in the way.
- Linking the source files in projects targeting different frameworks causes another problem: it's not possible to open the same source file in different projects. VS will inform you of the fact and then show the already-open source file from another project. This affects IntelliSense, especially with the conditional compilation. Not a show-stopper, but many times you'll open a file and then have to close it and re-open it (and then go back to the position where you were).
- Unit tests on VS2010 have to target the 4.0 framework. So any testing on other framework versions has to be done in a non-VS2010 way. I haven't found a good solution for this yet; it doesn't affect Nito.Linq because unit testing the 4.0 variants tests all the code.

I did ask the [Rx team](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) how they handled this situation (they support 3.5, 4.0, SL3, and SL4 with the same codebase). Apparently, they use a custom in-house tool to create metadata-only versions of the runtime assemblies and then combine these into a superset-profile containing the merged metadata-only assemblies. The project is built against this superset-profile and a post-compilation "retargeting" is done to change the project's profile to one of the normal profiles.

I briefly [played around](http://nitolinq.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/46229#1130899) with building an open-source equivalent of the Rx team's tool, but ran into too many "underdocumented" snags. It should be possible in theory, but I figured it would take way too much time for anyone without the correct contacts inside Microsoft.

Comment: Update: Microsoft released last week a toolset called [Portable Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx). It uses metadata-only assemblies with superset-profiles as I described above. Unfortunately, it does not support SL or .NET below 4.0 (also not supporting any plain-CF targets) and requires patches to the runtimes (SL 4.0.60129.0 and .NET KB2468871). It builds an actual portable binary, rather than multiple binaries; so platform-specific functionality must be done using [a form of dependency injection](http://tinyurl.com/6esdpdu) from platform-specific libraries.