# What is the best strategy to support .NET 3.0 and .NET 4.0?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I would like to support .NET 3.0 and .NET 4.0 for my project.
My current solution is to have two project files - one for each version of .NET.
Is there a better / more convenient way?

Comment: Are you using and specific .Net 4.0 features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer to this question: [Build System for Targeting Multiple .NET Versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212101/build-system-for-targeting-multiple-net-versions/3214266#3214266)

The short answer is that there isn't an easy way to do this. The best I've found is to use separate projects (with #define's set up appropriately) and use "Add as Link" to share code.